# Is it correct to use these six cases instead of four as specified in the solutions manual for $|a+b|-|b|$

Tags: real-analysis

In Spivak's Chapter 1 - Problem 10, there's a question that asks about removing the absolute value signs, taking seperate cases if necessary.

In one of the questions, the problem is: $|a+b|-|b|$

In my answer, i ended up taking four cases of the four possible combinations of a and b being either greater than or less than zero.
In the cases $a > 0, b < 0$ and $a < 0, b > 0$ the answer needed two more sub-cases, making a total of six cases.

The author however just uses four cases by comparing only for the four possible combinations of $a \ge b$ or $a \lt b$ and $b > 0$ or $b < 0$.

I understand that the author's approach is a much cleaner approach to the problem, but is the other approach also acceptable?

Comment: You are never really interested in the sign of $a$, only the sign of $a+b$ and of $b$, so checking for $a < 0$ and $a>0$ reduces readability and is unnecessary, but it's not techncally incorrect per se.

Comment: Are you sure that the author considers the condition $a > b$ (and not maybe $a > -b$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong mathematically, but it is not perfect, either.

Let us take a look at $|a + b|$. Why do you consider cases $a>0$ and $a<0$? It it irrelevant, whether $a$ is greater that or less than $0$. The only thing that absolute values "sees" is the sum of $a$ and $b$. The outcome depend only on whether $a + b \geq 0$ (i.e $a\geq -b$) or $a + b < 0$.

Take a look at your cases $b > 0> a$ and $b > a >0$. If you didn't do anything wrong, you should got the same results there.

Comment: The condition $a+b\ge0$ has nothing to do with $a\ge b$.

Comment: @egreg Oops, I will corect this.